# Click not triggered on Javascript function that submits to Facebook Pixel

Tags: javascript, jquery, facebook

The following code tracks the number of clicks on the element and then submits the result to Facebook Pixel. However, the event is not triggered for some reason.

Thought it's a variable scope problem, changed `countClicks` to global but it didn't change anything.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  if(window.location.href.indexOf("products") > -1) {    

    var countClicks = 0;

    $(".product-single__thumbnail-image").click(function () {
        countClicks++;  
      });

    function firePixelSlideshowView() {
      fbq('trackCustom', "ProductSlideshowImageView", {
        imageView: countClicks,
      });
    }

    window.onbeforeunload = function () {
        firePixelSlideshowView();   
            return null;
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Hi, I proposed an edit for a more specific title.

Comment: so where exactly does it not work? right now, we don´t even know if the firePixelSlideshowView function gets called correctly, or if the jquery event listener does not work for you. then, you need to check the browser console for errors/warnings. and you can check the network tab if something is happening. please debug your code first.

Comment: If I knew how to do all that I wouldn't be asking on StackOverflow :) Way to downvote newbies, thanks

Comment: Not sure if trying to fire of functions that need to make HTTP requests in a beforeunload handler is such a good idea. Browsers tend to cancel pending requests when the main window gets navigated elsewhere.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem by using jQuery unload() function instead of vanilla Javascript and it worked.